# useParams for category products

Tags: css, reactjs, sanity

I am new with React JS and I am trying to be able to call the list of products by their category. That should be done from the Navbar, but I could not sort it out. If there is someone to help me with it I would much appreciate it. Below is the code.

this is my route page

```
const Pages = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />}/>
        <Route path="/products/:_type" element={<Products />}/>
    </Routes>
  )
}
```

this one is for fetching products

```
let params = useParams()

  const[shopProducts,setShopProducts] = useState([])
  const[ifFetch,setIfFetch] = useState(false)
  const getProducts = async (name) =>{
  
    const query = `*[_type ==${name}]`
    await client.fetch(query).then((res) => {
      
      //console.log(res)
      setShopProducts(res)
      console.log(shopProducts)
      setIfFetch(true)
    })
   

    }

    
  
useEffect(()=>{
  getProducts(params.type)
},[params.type,ifFetch])
```

and this is my link from navbar

```
 <NavLink to={'/products/men'}>Men</NavLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Route page**

```
const Pages = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />}/>
        <Route path="products/:type" element={<Products />}/>
    </Routes>
  )
}
```

And get route parameter like this way -

```
let { type } = useParams()

const[shopProducts,setShopProducts] = useState([])
const[ifFetch,setIfFetch] = useState(false)
    
  
useEffect(()=> {

  client.fetch(`https://ho4y55im.api.sanity.io/v2021-10-21/data/production?query=${type}`)
   .then((res)=> { 
      setShopProducts(res) 
      setIfFetch(true)
   } 

},[type, ifFetch])
```

Comment: useEffect(()=>{
  const getResponse = async ()=>{
    //const query = `*[_type== "men"]`
    client.fetch(`https://ho4y55im.api.sanity.io/v2021-10-21/data/production?query=*[_type ==${type}]`)
      .then((res)=>{
      setShopProducts(res)
      setIfFetch(true)
      console.log(shopProducts)
    })}
    getResponse()
   
},[type,ifFetch])

i am getting this error 
{"error":{"description":"unexpected end-of-file, expected expression","end":86,"query":"https://ho4y55im.api.sanity.io/v2021-10-21/data/production?query=*[_type ==undefined]","start":86,"type":"queryParseError"}}

Comment: I have edited the code. Use fetch right this way. Make change your query according to your api documentation. I just give you the idea how to implement fetch.